# Add Insert Button to Tiny MCE

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, text-editor, tinymce-4

I am developing my own plugin to added into tinyMCE v4 plugin's list, until now I have reached to add a button in menu and open the pop-up when I click on it than I can fill out the form with data after that it added to tinyMCE editor, but I have some problems when I want to edit these informations, I tried to add some script but still not work,

Here's is my source code:

Note 1: onclick works for adding new button

Note 2: onpostrender works for editing button

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('buttonlink', function(editor, url) {
// Add a button that opens a window
editor.addButton('buttonlink', {
    text: 'Insert Button',
    tooltip: "Insert/edit Button link",
    icon: false,
    onclick: function() {
        // Open window
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Button',
            body: [
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Title'},
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'link', label: 'Link'},
                {type: 'listbox', name: 'colorBtn', label: 'Button Color',values:
                        [
                            {value:"008000", text:"Green"},
                            {value:"0000FF", text:"Blue"},
                            {value:"000000", text:"Black"},
                            {value:"993300", text:"Burnt orange"},
                            {value:"333300", text:"Dark olive"},
                            {value:"003300", text:"Dark green"},
                            {value:"003366", text:"Dark azure"},
                            {value:"000080", text:"Navy Blue"},
                            {value:"333399", text:"Indigo"},
                            {value:"333333", text:"Very dark gray"},
                            {value:"800000", text:"Maroon"},
                            {value:"FF6600", text:"Orange"},
                            {value:"808000", text:"Olive"},
                            {value:"008080", text:"Teal"},
                            {value:"666699", text:"Grayish blue"},
                            {value:"808080", text:"Gray"},
                            {value:"FF0000", text:"Red"},
                            {value:"FF9900", text:"Amber"},
                            {value:"99CC00", text:"Yellow green"},
                            {value:"339966", text:"Sea green"},
                            {value:"33CCCC", text:"Turquoise"},
                            {value:"3366FF", text:"Royal blue"},
                            {value:"800080", text:"Purple"},
                            {value:"999999", text:"Medium gray"},
                            {value:"FF00FF", text:"Magenta"},
                            {value:"FFCC00", text:"Gold"},
                            {value:"FFFF00", text:"Yellow"},
                            {value:"00FF00", text:"Lime"},
                            {value:"00FFFF", text:"Aqua"},
                            {value:"00CCFF", text:"Sky blue"},
                            {value:"993366", text:"Red violet"},
                            {value:"FFFFFF", text:"White"},
                            {value:"FF99CC", text:"Pink"},
                            {value:"FFCC99", text:"Peach"},
                            {value:"FFFF99", text:"Light yellow"},
                            {value:"CCFFCC", text:"Pale green"},
                            {value:"CCFFFF", text:"Pale cyan"},
                            {value:"99CCFF", text:"Light sky blue"},
                            {value:"CC99FF", text:"Plum"}
                        ]
                },
                {type: 'listbox', name: 'colorText', label: 'Text Color',values:
                        [
                            {value:"FFFFFF", text:"White"},
                            {value:"000000", text:"Black"},
                            {value:"993300", text:"Burnt orange"},
                            {value:"333300", text:"Dark olive"},
                            {value:"003300", text:"Dark green"},
                            {value:"003366", text:"Dark azure"},
                            {value:"000080", text:"Navy Blue"},
                            {value:"333399", text:"Indigo"},
                            {value:"333333", text:"Very dark gray"},
                            {value:"800000", text:"Maroon"},
                            {value:"FF6600", text:"Orange"},
                            {value:"808000", text:"Olive"},
                            {value:"008000", text:"Green"},
                            {value:"008080", text:"Teal"},
                            {value:"0000FF", text:"Blue"},
                            {value:"666699", text:"Grayish blue"},
                            {value:"808080", text:"Gray"},
                            {value:"FF0000", text:"Red"},
                            {value:"FF9900", text:"Amber"},
                            {value:"99CC00", text:"Yellow green"},
                            {value:"339966", text:"Sea green"},
                            {value:"33CCCC", text:"Turquoise"},
                            {value:"3366FF", text:"Royal blue"},
                            {value:"800080", text:"Purple"},
                            {value:"999999", text:"Medium gray"},
                            {value:"FF00FF", text:"Magenta"},
                            {value:"FFCC00", text:"Gold"},
                            {value:"FFFF00", text:"Yellow"},
                            {value:"00FF00", text:"Lime"},
                            {value:"00FFFF", text:"Aqua"},
                            {value:"00CCFF", text:"Sky blue"},
                            {value:"993366", text:"Red violet"},
                            {value:"FF99CC", text:"Pink"},
                            {value:"FFCC99", text:"Peach"},
                            {value:"FFFF99", text:"Light yellow"},
                            {value:"CCFFCC", text:"Pale green"},
                            {value:"CCFFFF", text:"Pale cyan"},
                            {value:"99CCFF", text:"Light sky blue"},
                            {value:"CC99FF", text:"Plum"}
                        ]
                },
            ],
            onsubmit: function(e) {
                // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                if(e.data.title != null && e.data.title != "") {
                    editor.insertContent('<a href="' + e.data.link + '" target="_blank" id="btn-link-plugin" class="btn" style="color: #' + e.data.colorText + '; background: #' + e.data.colorBtn + '">' + e.data.title + '</a>');
                }
            }
        });
    },
    onpostrender: function (buttonApi) {
        var btn = this;
        var editorEventCallback = function (e) {
            var IDElement = e.element.getAttribute('id');
            if (btn._id == "mceu_22" && IDElement == "btn-link-plugin") {

                var link = e.element.getAttribute('data-mce-href');
                var style = e.element.getAttribute('style');
                var text = e.element.text;

                var res = style.split(";");
                var colorStyle = res[0].split(":");
                var backgroundStyle = res[1].split(":");
                colorStyle[1] = colorStyle[1].replace(/\s+/g, '');
                backgroundStyle[1] = backgroundStyle[1].replace(/\s+/g, '');

                var colorTxt = colorStyle[1].substr(1);
                var backgroundTxt = backgroundStyle[1].substr(1);

                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Button',
                    body: [
                        {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Title', value: text},
                        {type: 'textbox', name: 'link', label: 'Link', value: link},
                        {
                            type: 'listbox', name: 'colorBtn', label: 'Button Color', values:
                                [
                                    {value: "008000", text: "Green"},
                                    {value: "0000FF", text: "Blue"},
                                    {value: "000000", text: "Black"},
                                ],
                            onPostRender: function() {
                                this.value(backgroundTxt);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'listbox', name: 'colorText', label: 'Text Color', values:
                                [
                                    {value: "FFFFFF", text: "White"},
                                    {value: "000000", text: "Black"},
                                    {value: "993300", text: "Burnt orange"},
                                    {value: "333300", text: "Dark olive"},
                                ],
                            onPostRender: function() {
                                this.value(colorTxt);
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function (e) {
                        // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                        if (e.data.title != null && e.data.title != "") {

                            editor.insertContent('<a href="' + e.data.link + '" target="_blank" id="btn-link-plugin" class="btn" style="color: #' + e.data.colorText + '; background: #' + e.data.colorBtn + '">' + e.data.title + '</a>');
                            editor.off('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        editor.on('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
        return function (buttonApi) {
            console.log("off");
            editor.off('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
        }
    }
});

 return {
    getMetadata: function () {
        return  {
            name: "Button Link plugin",
            url: "https://capoffshore.com"
        };
    }
  };
});
```

This is the pop-up for creating new button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('buttonlink', function(editor, url) {
// Add a button that opens a window
var params = [];
editor.addButton('buttonlink', {
    text: 'Insert Button',
    tooltip: "Insert/edit Button link",
    icon: false,
    onclick: function(e) {
        // Open window
        var btn = this;

        var text = "";
        var link = "";
        var backgroundTxt = "0000FF";
        var colorTxt = "FFFFFF";

        if (typeof params['text'] !== 'undefined') {
            text = params['text'];
        }
        if (typeof params['link'] !== 'undefined') {
            link = params['link'];
        }
        if (typeof params['backgroundTxt'] !== 'undefined') {
            backgroundTxt = params['backgroundTxt'];
        }
        if (typeof params['colorTxt'] !== 'undefined') {
            colorTxt = params['colorTxt'];
        }

        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Button',
            body: [
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Title', value: text},
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'link', label: 'Link', value: link},
                {type: 'listbox', name: 'colorBtn', label: 'Button Color',values:
                        [
                            {value:"0000FF", text:"Blue"},
                            {value:"008000", text:"Green"}
                        ],
                    onPostRender: function() {
                        this.value(backgroundTxt);
                    }
                },
                {type: 'listbox', name: 'colorText', label: 'Text Color',values:
                        [
                            {value:"FFFFFF", text:"White"},
                            {value:"000000", text:"Black"}
                        ],
                    onPostRender: function() {
                        this.value(colorTxt);
                    }
                },
            ],
            onsubmit: function(e) {
                // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                if(e.data.title != null && e.data.title != "") {

                    var link = e.data.link;
                    var title = e.data.title;
                    var colorText = e.data.colorText;
                    var colorBtn = e.data.colorBtn;

                    if (e.data.link == null || e.data.link == "" || typeof e.data.link === 'undefined') {
                        link = "#";
                    }

                    tinymce.activeEditor.dom.remove(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.get("btn-link-plugin"));

                    editor.insertContent('<a href="' + link+ '" target="_blank" id="btn-link-plugin" class="btn" style="color: #' + colorText + '; background: #' + colorBtn + '">' + title + '</a>');
                }
            }
        });
    },
    onpostrender: function (buttonApi) {
        var btn = this;
        var editorEventCallback = function (e) {
            var IDElement = e.element.getAttribute('id');
            if (btn._id == "mceu_22" && IDElement == "btn-link-plugin") {
                btn.active(true);
                var link = e.element.getAttribute('data-mce-href');
                var style = e.element.getAttribute('style');
                var text = e.element.text;

                var res = style.split(";");
                var colorStyle = res[0].split(":");
                var backgroundStyle = res[1].split(":");
                colorStyle[1] = colorStyle[1].replace(/\s+/g, '');
                backgroundStyle[1] = backgroundStyle[1].replace(/\s+/g, '');

                var colorTxt = colorStyle[1].substr(1);
                var backgroundTxt = backgroundStyle[1].substr(1);

                params['link'] = link;
                params['text'] = text;
                params['colorTxt'] = colorTxt;
                params['backgroundTxt'] = backgroundTxt;
            }
        };
        editor.on('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
    }
});

return {
    getMetadata: function () {
        return  {
            name: "Button Link plugin",
            url: "https://capoffshore.com"
        };
    }
};
});
```